# What do reshigh and reslow mean?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I'm wondering what `reshigh` and `reslow` mean in the `portfolio.optim` function in the package tseries.

Comment: Please try adding some relevant tags and references

Comment: Try `?portofolio.optim`: `a vector specifying the (optional) lower/upper bound on allowed portfolio weights.`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tseries/docs/portfolio.optim) :

> *reslow*
>
> a vector specifying the (optional) lower bound on allowed portfolio weights.
>
> *reshigh*
>
> a vector specifying the (optional) upper bound on allowed portfolio weights.